# How can I rate limit/packet shape/traffic shape on Solaris

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, traffic-shaping, nexenta

I have an TCP server application running on a Nexenta NCP 3 box.  I would like to limit how much outgoing bandwidth it can use.  Is it possible in Solaris to rate limit an application like I can in Linux?

I've seen mention of IPQoS and Crossbow, but can't find anything that tying it all together.

Answer (score 2):

Crossbow is AMAZING. It can do some many things really simply. What you want to look at is the usage of the [flowadm](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1462/flowadm-1m.html#scrolltoc) command.

What you are looking to do is just a one line command that will look very much like the following :

```
flowadm add-flow -l bge0 -a transport=UDP -p maxbw=100M, priority=low limit-udp-1
```

Obviously, you want to replace the appropriate information.

Here is another example that will most likely suit you better.

```
flowadm add-flow -l xnf0 -a remote_ip=193.49.161.207,remote_port=43833 flow-tcp-app
flowadm set-flowprop -p maxbw=8M flow-tcp-app
```

That's all you've gotta do. You may be looking at local_ip instead of remote_ip but that doesn't change much. No needs for zones if you don't need them. Nice, isn't it ?

Comment: I tried this, but ran into an limitation of Crossbow.  Where I wanted to limit the app down to 15 KiB/s Crossbow could only go down to 1.5 MBit/s (size of a ethernet frame)

Comment: That's right indeed. Crossbow is not really made for ADSL lines and such.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to install that application in a zone. This zone would have a dedicated vnic with crossbow bandwidth limitation enabled. NAT would be used for allowing ingoing/outgoing zone trafic.